# Switch UITextField keyboard from numbers to alphabet after user hits space

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

I want my Keyboard to change from UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation mode to normal text mode after the user hits space.

So he can easily type something like "34 loops".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, you cannot get direct input notifications, but there's a solution I can think of.

Implement the following delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

The replacement string will, as its name states, contain the string that wants to replace the existing string in the text field. What you could do is check the last character of this string, and if it is indeed a space, then change the keyboard type:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    char lastCharacter = [string characterAtIndex:[string length] - 1]; //Get the last input character in the ext field.
    if(lastCharacter == ' ')
    {
        //The last character is a space, so...
        textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        [textField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Simply setting `keyboardType` won't change the current keyboard if it's already visible. You also need to call `resignFirstResponder` then `becomeFirstResponder` on the text field.

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by Leonnears mostly answers the simple case, but there are many issues you need to consider. What happens if the user types `34`, then a space, then delete? What happens when the user moves the caret from the end of `loops` to somewhere in the number part?

It all starts to get more difficult to cover each case. But more importantly, it starts to get annoying for the user as the keyboard starts changing on them. It makes it very difficult to just type in the text. I've never seen an app do what you propose and there is a good reason.

Let the user use the normal keyboard like they are used to. Everyone knows how to switch between letter and numbers. Having the keyboard automatically change will be unusual and confusing.

Comment: While my answer can deal with almost everything (dealing with the range and by checking the amount of characters inserted vs. the amount of characters that were already there), I agree with this answer. it's probably something you shouldn't do. By default iOS allows you to input numbers and letters. The user could definitely get annoyed after a while.

Comment: You are absolutely right in most cases. However, in some scenarios the above solution is very convenient for the user e.g. if you have dozens of fields in a list where each entry is with a number + text: 

"34 loops, 12 froops, 45 foo, ..."